# Convertir correctamente una sentencia mysql al query builder de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Buen día, primero que nada agradezco que se tomen la molestia de revisar mi inquietud

Llevo un poco mas de 4 meses de usar laravel, pero últimamente me he sentido limitado por eloquent con las consultas sql que suelo hacer, he visto la documentación de laravel pero no termino de comprender, hay algo llamado DB::raw  lo cual me permite realizar mi consulta sql sin eloquent, pero he investigado y usarlo de esta forma no es recomendable, también he usado los query builder, bueno sin mas, mi duda es esta, tengo el siguiente query(normalmente siempre los hago así para no perder la costumbre de la practica tradicional y luego construyó mi query builder):

Tengo este query, pero noten que he puesto un alias `rq` en el `from resultquestionnaires rq` , en eloquent aún no descubro como hacerlo, pues hasta donde tengo entendido el from no se usa, ya que se hace referencia a la tabla a través del modelo, eso es uno el from y lo otro es sobre como usar correctamente `as` ya que para consultas extensas es muy útil

cual seria la forma correcta de pasarlo a eloquent o querybuilder aplicando buenas practicas, les agradezco si tienen algún post que me sirva.

gracias de antemano.

este es mi query:

```
 select rq.id AS id,qnn.name  AS Cuestionario,
 qs.statement AS Preguntas,qs.option_a AS
 Opción_A,qs.option_b AS Opción_B,qs.option_c AS Opción_C,
 qs.option_d AS Opción_D,(case rq.correctoption_id 
 when '1' 
 then 'A' 
 when '2' 
 then 'B' 
 when '3' 
 then 'C'
 when '4' 
 then 'D' 
 end) 
 AS RespuestaSeleccionada
 ,co.option AS RespuestaCorrecta,
 (case rq.correctoption_id
 when qs.correctoption_id 
 then 'correcto' 
 else 'Mal' 
 end) AS Correctas
 ,p.names AS Nombres
 ,p.lastnames
 AS Apellidos,p.document AS Documento,p.phone AS Cel,usr.email AS Correo
 from resultquestionnaires rq 
 join questionnaires qnn 
 on qnn.id = rq.questionnaire_id 
 join questions qs on qs.id = rq.question_id
 join users usr on usr.id = rq.user_id 
 join correctoptions co on co.id = qs.correctoption_id  
 join peoples p on p.id = usr.people_id  
 order by rq.id
```

Lo que he intentado

```
$ResultUser=ResultQuestionnaire::select('resultquestionnaires.user_id','users.people_id',
        'peoples.names','resultquestionnaires.repetition_id','resultquestionnaires.questionnaire_id'
        ,'resultquestionnaires.score','resultquestionnaires.question_id','questions.statement')

            ->join('users','users.id','=','resultquestionnaires.user_id')
            ->join('peoples','peoples.id','=','users.people_id')
            ->join('questions','questions.id','=','resultquestionnaires.question_id')
            ->whereNotNull('resultquestionnaires.score')
            ->where('resultquestionnaires.user_id',$userId)
            ->where('resultquestionnaires.repetition_id',$repetitionId)
            ->where('resultquestionnaires.questionnaire_id',$questionnaireId)
            ->get();
```

modelo ResultQuestionnaire

```
class ResultQuestionnaire extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'resultquestionnaires';
    protected $fillable =
        [  'score','questionnaire_id','user_id',
        'question_id','correctoption_id','repetition_id','pass'];

    public function questionnaire(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Questionnaire','questionnaire_id');
    }
    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question','question_id');
    }
    public function correctoption(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Correctoption','correctoption_id');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\user','user_id');
    }
    public function repetition(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Repetition','repetition_id');
    }

}
```

modelo Question

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'image', 'statement', 'option_a',
        'option_b', 'option_c','option_d',
        'correctoption_id','questionnaire_id',

    ];
    protected $table ='questions';

    public function questionnaire(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Questionnaire','questionnaire_id');

    }
    public function correctoption(){
        return$this->belongsTo('App\CorrectOption', 'correctoption_id');
    }
    public function resultQuestionnaire()
    {
        return$this->hasMany('App\ResultQuestionnaire');
    }
}
```

modelo people

```
class People extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'document', 'names','lastnames', 'datebirth',
        'phone', 'addres', 'jobtitle_id', 'area_id',
    ];
//para indicar a la tabla que pertenece
    protected $table = 'peoples';

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
    public function area(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Area','area_id');
    }
    public function jobtitle(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Jobtitle','jobtitle_id');
    }

}
```

modelo CorrectOption

```
class CorrectOption extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'correctoptions';
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Question');
    }
    public function resultQuestionnaire()
    {
        return$this->hasMany('App\ResultQuestionnaire');
    }
}
```

Modelo Repetition

```
class Repetition extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'quantity','questionnaire_id','user_id',
    ];
    public function questionnaire(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Questionnaire','questionnaire_id');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\user','user_id');
    }
    public function resultquestionnaire(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ResultQuestionnaire');
    }

}
```

Modelo area y jobtitle

```
class Area extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
         'name','description',
    ];

    public function people(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\People','id_people','id');
    }
}

class Jobtitle extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title','description',
    ];
    public function people(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\People','id_people', 'id');
    }
}
```

modelo user

```
public function people(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\People');
    }
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
    public function questionnaires(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Questionnaire');

    }
    public function resultquestionnaire()
    {
        return$this->hasMany('App\ResultQuestionnaire');
    }
    public function repetitions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Repetition');
    }
```

Comment: en el caso de ser solo select sin condicional y muy complejos lo mejor es utilizar `db::raw("tu query!")`

Comment: Si tengo las relaciones definidas, utilicé querybuilder pero cuando quiero nombrar con un alias la tabla madre, por decirlo así, quedo ahí, en el from

Comment: @BetaM se torna mas compleja el agarrar una query extensa y combertirla a eloquent que utilizar directamente db::raw y en este caso no hay un condicion como tal para evitar `sqlinjenction`

Comment: de hecho tengo 3 condiciones, no las mostré ahí por que necesito aclarar mi duda

Comment: @BetaM ok, ya los agrego

Comment: @BetaM ya agregue lo que me pediste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partimos de tomar la consulta que ya tienes construida por las siguientes razones:

- Construir la query por medio de sus relaciones así como de `selects` personalizados para la data que quieres obtener extendería demasiado la respuesta
- La consulta actual ya la tienes avanzada y sobre esa podemos hacer los cambios o correcciones según sea necesario
- Para el case tus `CASE WHEN` es mejor mantener su sintaxis a nivel de sql y pasarlos en el método `selectRaw`, simplificará la lectura y estructura de tu consulta

Ahora bien para lograr darle el alias a tu entidad `ResultQuestionnaire` puedes:

Declararar la propiedad [`$table`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) en tu modelo donde escribirás el nombre de la tabla que representa a dicho modelo y justo ahi colocarle el alias deseado, mas o menos así:

```
protected $table = 'tabla AS alias';
```

De modo que al construir tu consulta quede mas o menos así:

```
Modelo::select('alias.propiedad', .................)
```

De no ser así podemos hacer uso del [facade `DB` para ejecutar tus consultas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries), donde pasaremos como argumento del método `table` el nombre de la tabla y el alias que deseamos asignarle

Consulta (basada en la última propuesta):

```
DB::table('resultQuestionnaires AS rq')
    ->selectRaw('
                    rq.id AS id,
                    qnn.name  AS Cuestionario,
                    qs.statement AS Preguntas,
                    qs.option_a AS Opción_A,
                    qs.option_b AS Opción_B,
                    qs.option_c AS Opción_C,
                    qs.option_d AS Opción_D,
                    (case rq.correctoption_id 
                         when "1" 
                             then "A" 
                             when "2" 
                             then "B" 
                             when "3" 
                             then "C"
                             when "4" 
                             then "D" 
                         end) AS RespuestaSeleccionada,co.option AS RespuestaCorrecta,
                    (case rq.correctoption_id
                         when qs.correctoption_id 
                            then "correcto" 
                         else "Mal" 
                         end) AS Correctas,
                    p.names AS Nombres,
                    p.lastnames AS Apellidos,
                    p.document AS Documento,
                    p.phone AS Cel,
                    usr.email AS Correo
            ')->join('questionnaires AS qnn', 'qnn.id', '=', 'rq.questionnaire_id')
            ->join('questions AS qs', 'qs.id', '=', 'rq.question_id')
            ->join('users AS usr', 'usr.id', '=', 'rq.user_id')
            ->join('correctoptions AS co', 'co.id', '=', 'qs.correctoption_id')
            ->join('peoples AS p', 'p.id', '=', 'usr.people_id')
            ->orderBy('rq.id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: excelente gracias, me resolviste la duda sobre como utilizar los alias, pero entonces utilizar los métodos que terminan con `raw` es confiable ?, no lo hice con raw por lo que te pregunto.

Comment: Si mas tarde lo escribo @CamiloMancipe

Comment: Los métodos como whereRaw no son inseguros, si pasas los valores dinámicos en el array de bindings que espera dicho método, por otro lado construir una consulta con DB::raw si no atiendes al punto anterior lo vuelve insegura y además pierdes todos los beneficios que Eloquent como ORM te ofrece mas aún a nivel de las relaciones

Comment: Gracias amigo @BetaM, muy claro